# DefaultInterceptor VirtualMethod Not Working On BaseClass

Tags: unity-container

I am trying to have a baseclass and register default interception using unity. I am also registering each derived type before resolving, but its not working. I would expect the BaseMethod to be intercepted here but it is not.

```
 public class AbstractResponse
{
    private string name;

    public virtual void BaseMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}

 public class DocumentResponse:AbstractResponse
{
    public virtual void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Test Method");
    }

}




var container = new UnityContainer(); container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
                 container.RegisterType<AbstractResponse>(
                 new DefaultInterceptor<VirtualMethodInterceptor>(),
                 new DefaultInterceptionBehavior<TraceBehavior>()).
                 RegisterType<AbstractResponse,DocumentResponse>();

container.Resolve<DocumentResponse>().BaseMethod();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just gone a little wrong on your registration code - you are actually calling RegisterType twice in your code sample, and the second registration is overwriting the first one. Switch it to something like this and it will work fine: -

```
container.RegisterType<AbstractResponse, DocumentResponse>(
   new DefaultInterceptor<VirtualMethodInterceptor>(),
   new DefaultInterceptionBehavior<TraceBehaviour>());
```

So this says "Register AbstractResponse and map it to DocumentResponse. Then, using the VirtualMethodInterceptor, apply the TraceBehaviour."

You can always see if the interception is active by seeing the type that is returned on Resolve - if it's the (in this case) AbstractResponse then it hasn't worked; if you get back some funky Unity-generated type name then it's working.